# How can I unit test Alex code?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, monads, lexer

I'm writing a lexer in Alex with the monad wrapper. It's not behaving as I expect, and I would like to write some unit tests for it. I can write unit tests for lexing a single token by doing:

```
runAlex "foo" alexMonadScan `shouldBe` Right TokenFoo
```

but I don't know how to test that the string "foo bar" gets lexed to `[TokenFoo, TokenBar]`.

Given that `Token` is my token type, I'd need a function like `runAlex` that has the type `String -> Alex [Token] -> Either String [Token]`, but I don't know how to transform `alexMonadScan` so that it has the type `Alex [Token]` rather than `Alex Token`.

I tried

```
runAlex "foo bar" (liftM (:[]) alexMonadScan) `shouldBe` [TokenFoo, TokenBar]
```

which seems to have the right type, but it returns `Right [TokenEOF]`, apparently dropping the tokens it saw along the way.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please do not unit test me, it makes me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @AlexM. Why? Have you got something to hide?

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ I-it's not like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function `alexScanTokens :: String -> [token]` which you can use.

It's defined in the file `templates/wrappers.hs`

Here's a monadic version I found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tamarin-prover-0.4.0.0/src/interactive-only-src/Lexer.x):

```
alexScanTokens :: String -> Either String [Keyword]
alexScanTokens inp = runAlex inp gather
  where
  gather = do
    t <- alexMonadScan
    case trace (show t) t of
      EOF -> return [EOF]
      _   -> (t:) `liftM` gather
```

Comment: Does that work with the monad wrapper? I was under the impression it only worked with the basic wrapper. I'm getting `Not in scope: alexScanTokens` when I try to use it.

Comment: Answer updated. To get `alexScanTokens` in scope you need to define one of `ALEX_BASIC`, `ALEX_BASIC_BYTESTRING`, or another `ALEX_...` symbol. See [here](https://github.com/simonmar/alex/blob/master/templates/wrappers.hs#L376)